# saving cron job in ubuntu

Tags: cron, vi

I am new to ubuntu and cron job. I have entered the following into my command line:

```
       crontab -e
```

and I get the following output: "no crontab for teddy - using an empty one 888"

Then I enter when I want it to execute (I believe this is right?... I want it to run once a day, everyday at 8pm):

```
                 00 18 * * * /*****/*****/****/test.php
```

Here is my problem, I dont know how to exit back to the command line. Everything I type gives me weird looking letters and enter (return) doesn't do anything. I have read that this will do the job

```
                 ESC : w q
```

but its not working for me. I tried typing that in, I tried pressing them at the same time, I tried pressing one at a time. Nothing, still stuck. When I press ESC, it comes out as ^[.

This is probably  very easy question and I apologize if it is stupid but I have been stuck for sometime. Any help would much appreciated.

Thank you

P.S. I read somewhere that if this is your first job that you need to to do an end line at the end of the cronjob... is this a simple enter key press or actually typing \n?

Comment: This question is off-topic and belongs to http://askubuntu.com/ . Regarding the question: are you sure you are using Vi to edit the file? Because if it's an other editor your Vi commands won't get you far. Plus 8 pm = 20 not 18 (which is 6 pm).

Comment: From your shell prompt, what is the output of `echo $EDITOR ; echo $VISUAL`?

Comment: @vstm, the OP is using Ubuntu, but the question is valid for any flavour of Linux or Unix.  Vixie Cron and viworks the same way everywhere.

Comment: What is vi? I am in my terminal on macbook pro connecting to my ubuntu server... Do i need to be directly on the ubuntu server? And yes your right 20= 8 pm.

Comment: @KeithThompson I get an empty line followed by my command prompt on the next line... for both commands

Comment: If neither `$EDITOR` nor `$VISUAL` is set, `crontab -e` asks you which editor you want to use (at least on my Ubuntu 11.04 and 11.10 systems).  If you're using `nano`, there should be a prompt at the bottom of the screen telling you that control-X exits.  If you're using `ed`, type `.` on a line by itself, then `q` on a line by itself.  For emacs, control-X control-Q.  Then set up your environment so `$EDITOR` points to your preferred editor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Teddy13, let's get some clarifications here.

Ubuntu is the distribution of Linux you are using.  None of the commands you're typing are exclusive to Ubuntu.

You're asking questions about two separate issues.  One is "How do I write a crontab".  The other is "How do I use vi, the default editor of the crontab command".

First, `man crontab` to review the format for entries in the file.  Note that cron runs things that are executable from the shell.  You can only run your "test.php" script if it is structured like a shell script, with the first line containing "shell magic" (i.e. something like `#!/usr/local/bin/php`).

Second, while vi is a powerful and well-loved text editor, it's not the easiest to use.  I fully support any efforts you may make to learn how to use it, but until you're comfortable with it, you might want to consider switching to "pico" or "ee" or "joe", which are all much easier to learn, though they can do much less.  You can install joe, for example, with the command: `apt-get install joe` run as root.  Then to use joe to edit your crontab, add `export VISUAL=/usr/bin/joe` to the `.bashrc` file in your home directory.

There's a lot of background information you may want to get.  Read lots.  It's worth it.

**UPDATE** (per comment):

Here's the basic stuff you need to edit your crontab.

- `crontab -e`  ... as you now know, this edits your crontab file using $EDITOR or $VISUAL, which defaults to `vi`.

  - Inside vi, you are always in one of three modes. MOVEMENT mode lets you move around the file using arrows or H, J, K and L.  You can delete lines with "dd" or characters with "x".  EDIT mode lets you add or change text.  From Movement mode, use "i" or "a" or "o" to enter Edit mode in different ways.  Read docs for details.  Third, COMMAND mode can be reached by hitting ":" from Movement mode.  From here, you can issue a variety of commands to save, search, bulk edit, etc.
  - From Movement mode, you can save your file and exit using "ZZ".  From edit mode, you can do this with the command "wq" (hence the ":wq" mentioned elsewhere).
- **Alternately**, you can set a new crontab by piping information into the crontab command.  *Note that this will erase any existing crontab you may have.*  Run this in your shell updating the URL of your script as required:

  `echo "0 20 * * * wget http://example.com/path/to/file.php" | crontab -`
- `crontab -l` will show you what your current crontab contains.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE #2** (per comments below):

```
$ tmpfile=/tmp/foo.$$
$ crontab -l > $tmpfile
$ echo "30 6 * * * Mail -s wakeup pager@example.net <<< 'Time to wake up.'" >> $tmpfile
$ crontab - < $tmpfile && rm $tmpfile
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification ghoti... seems like a lot of work and perhaps currently out of my realm. Do you know any other ways I could have a daemon run a php script once daily everyday that isnt so difficult?

Comment: Well, cron is certainly the daemon you want to use for this task.  Tthe other advice you've gotten in answers here may give you hints on how to get this one cron job in place.  Rather than doing shell magic, you could use the "wget" command to "visit a URL", thereby executing the PHP as if it was hit by a web browser. `0 20 * * * wget http://example.com/path/to/file.php`  I'll add a bit more to my answer...

Comment: Thanks really appreciate this. I have used "emacs" before in the past so I just installed it and I tried to get it into emacs by typing EDITOR=emacs && crontab -e     but takes me to the same editor? or same place

Comment: If you are using bash as your shell, you should set this like: `export EDITOR=emacs`.  Also, I believe the VISUAL variable takes precedence over the EDITOR variable, so if $VISUAL=="vi", $EDITOR doesn't matter.  Try `export VISUAL=emacs` instead.  Or just use a pipe and skip the editor altogether.

Comment: Thank you so much ghoti. Could not have done it without you. Last question, promise. Using your alternate method, how can I add more cron jobs without deleting existing ones?

Comment: Well, piping input into `crontab -` will always override your existing crontab.  If you want to modify crontabs using a script, the solution would be to save the existing entries in a temp file using `crontab -l`, then include the temp file when you reset things with `crontab -`.  See update #2.

Answer (score 4):

You can try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. This will ask you for changes to save or not before exit. In that just give <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> so you will get out of there. Try it.

Comment: It gives me ^X  when I press cntl + X

Answer (score 0):

You need to press ZZ to exit (upper case 'z' twice) . Here is an article on setting up cron tabs - http://www.sophos.com/support/knowledgebase/article/12176.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... read the article but didn't seem to work. Does it make a difference if im accessing my ubuntu server from a terminal on mac?

Comment: I did: 00 18 * * * /*****/*****/****/test.phpZZ with no luck

Comment: no once you specify the entry , press your 'Esc' key and after that press ZZ

Comment: just did: 00 18 * * * /*****/*****/****/test.php^[ZZ        followed by pressing return and I get a "?". For me when I press esc it still gives me: ^[